# Check if data exist before saving in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am quite new to cake3 I don't know if how can manage to do this 
I have two

table `users and accounts`

users contain

```
Id,EmployeeId,Password,Logs
```

accounts contain

```
Id,EmployeeId,Password,Fname,Lname,Role
```

What I want to happen is before the data is save in users table it will check first if the Employee Id and Password is present in the accounts table how do I do this in cakephp 3?

I have this in one of my controllers

```
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Log Time Saved!.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
```

Comment: i haven't used cake `3.0` only `2.x`. maybe this can help  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html

Comment: any idea how is it done in cakephp 2.X

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? In your question you've asked about CakePHP 3, but then in your comment above stated CakePHP 2? Please clarify and update your question if it is incorrect.

Comment: im using cakephp 3.0 sir is just that i was thinking if there's anyway this is possible to be done in cakephp 2.0 maybe i can get the logic from that and maybe apply it in my project

Comment: If you cant do/ or dont want to do  this check in your controller There is beforeSave event which you can use in your model.

Comment: how is it possible in before save model

Comment: To that function cake is passing data you are going to save , it mean you have all info you need to query db and get if you necessary information is there or not.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 3:

You should use BeforeSave callback where the Entity object is passed as a parameter and you can use it to check if the same record exists and avoid from storing it again.

[From the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave):

> The Model.beforeSave event is fired before each entity is saved.
>   Stopping this event will abort the save operation. When the event is
>   stopped the result of the event will be returned.